# variable |= variable meaning?

Tags: java, variables, operators

I was looking trough some coding to extend my knowledge in Java and I came across the following line of code which I do not understand and googling returns nothing on the matter.

```
int metadata;
int facing;
metadata |= facing;
```

what does the |= mean/do is there documentation on this (Or more to the point what is this operation called)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"|" is boolean logical OR and placing the operand before "=" works pretty much the same as expressions like a += b (which means a = a + b).

So basically, **a |= b** is the same as **a = a | b**

List of all Java operands can be found [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/opsummary.html).

Answer (score 2):

It is the same as

```
metadata = metadata | facing;
```

More on Java's operators here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html

Answer (score 0):

This is shorthand for

```
metadata = metadata | facing;
```